# What seats are really available on an Emirates flight

Tags: air-travel, emirates

WHen seat configuration shows unavailable does it really mean unavailable or are some of those seats available closer to date of flight.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until @pnuts 's question is answered. Otherwise it's a great question with a real complicated answer.